# Who taught children to write on the wall

Tags: supernatural

In supernatural season 4 episode "Family remains" those two small children are dumped in the walls, they never saw light. they always live in the walls. When the family of 5 people comes to live in that house messages are written on walls "Go" and "Too late". Who wrote those messages in blood? Was it the two siblings who wrote on wall? If yes who taught them to read and write as they are always in the walls.

Comment: i think that's a conceptual mistake the makers of the show did.

Comment: There was a thing they established early on, somewhere in the beginning of season one. I'm pretty sure it's Sam's line, he tells someone that it's hard to connect trough the vail so sometimes the ghosts' (spirits') message gets garbled. Based on this I would guess that the writing on the wall was how their message "came through" from beyond th vail.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've seen the episode, so I'm going to borrow from some review sites for the plot.

From the [IMDb synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1222597/synopsis) (bolding mine):

> Sam confirms that he was indeed reading Rebecca's diary, and that
>   Rebecca had a daughter. But Mr. Gibson wanted to make sure that nobody
>   knew about the daughter because...well, guess who was the father?
>   Again, ew. Turns out Uncle Ted wasn't that far off. So: Dean and Sam
>   are dealing with a wild child of the inbred psychotic variety. But
>   they notice that her eyes are clouded over -- she's never seen light.
>   So they decide to draw her out. Kid's gotta eat, right? **Dad kept her
>   hidden, he had to feed her**. He has an idea of where.

From [TVRage.com](http://www.tvrage.com/Supernatural/episodes/741053/recap) (again, bolding mine):

> The Winchesters find **Gibson's housekeeper**, Mrs. Curry, who talks
>   about how Gibson kept to himself after his wife died giving birth to
>   their only daughter, and that years later the daughter Rebecca hung
>   herself. She doesn't know why Rebecca killed herself but provides the
>   brothers with photos. She notes that she did hear rustling noises in
>   the walls when she cleaned but never saw any rats. Sam and Dean
>   discover that both dead women were cremated, meaning their ghosts
>   can't be responsible.

These two quotes would seem to imply that the father kept the children for some unspecified amount of time until:

> Sam pulls Dean away and explains that according to the diary, Rebecca
>   had a daughter, sired by her father. Gibson hated Rebecca, who killed
>   herself, and then Gibson locked up his daughter until she broke free
>   and killed him.

Now, as far as I can tell, no time span is given for these events, and looking at some pictures of the girl, I'd estimate she's in her pre-teens at the time the episode takes place.  Maybe older if she's malnourished.  <sub>(And as an anecdote, to give a time scale, I was reading simple children's books a year before kindergarten.  A decade younger than Rebecca looks.)</sub>

We have no evidence as to how Gibson actually treated Rebecca's daughter.  According to this [sentence-by-sentence recap](http://www.tvchitchat.net/supernatural-family-remains-recap/) of the episode, we only know the daughter was locked up because that's what Gibson told Rebecca before she killed herself.  He may have tried to teach her.  She may have learned how to write some simple words.